# Can't edit UltraGrid?

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, checkbox, infragistics

thank you for taking your time to read my questions, I Have googled and read a lot of posts and nothing that I tried works, I'm using infragistisc in a Windows Desktop application, can you please tell me why I can't edit it? (I mean that when I click on it, it does nothing)

Designer:

```
 Me.mygrid.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
                Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
                Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.mygrid.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.AddNewBox.ButtonConnectorStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.None
    Appearance5.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Appearance = Appearance5
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.AutoFitStyle = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AutoFitStyle.ResizeAllColumns
    UltraGridBand1.AddButtonCaption = "DummyBand 1"
    UltraGridBand1.CardSettings.AllowSizing = False
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.BandsSerializer.Add(UltraGridBand1)
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.BorderStyle = Infragistics.Win.UIElementBorderStyle.Solid
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.GroupByBox.ShowBandLabels = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ShowBandLabels.None
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.MaxBandDepth = 1
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.MaxRowScrollRegions = 1
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddNew = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowAddNew.No
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColMoving = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowColMoving.NotAllowed
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowColSizing.None
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSwapping = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowColSwapping.NotAllowed
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowDelete = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.[False]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowGroupBy = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.[False]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowGroupMoving = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowGroupMoving.NotAllowed
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowFiltering = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.[False]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowLayoutCellSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowLayoutSizing.None
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowLayoutLabelSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowLayoutSizing.None
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowRowSummaries.[False]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowUpdate = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.[True]
    Appearance6.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CardAreaAppearance = Appearance6
    Appearance7.TextVAlignAsString = "Middle"
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellAppearance = Appearance7
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.RowSelect
    Appearance8.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(89, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(135, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(214, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance8.BackColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(7, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(59, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(150, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance8.BackGradientStyle = Infragistics.Win.GradientStyle.Vertical
    Appearance8.FontData.BoldAsString = "True"
    Appearance8.FontData.Name = "Arial"
    Appearance8.FontData.SizeInPoints = 10.0!
    Appearance8.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
    Appearance8.ThemedElementAlpha = Infragistics.Win.Alpha.Transparent
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderAppearance = Appearance8
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderClickAction = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.HeaderClickAction.SortMulti
    Appearance9.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.RowAlternateAppearance = Appearance9
    Appearance10.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(89, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(135, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(214, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance10.BackColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(7, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(59, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(150, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance10.BackGradientStyle = Infragistics.Win.GradientStyle.Vertical
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectorAppearance = Appearance10
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.[True]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.RowSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.RowSizing.Fixed
    Appearance11.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(251, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(230, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(148, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance11.BackColor2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(CType(CType(238, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(149, Byte), Integer), CType(CType(21, Byte), Integer))
    Appearance11.BackGradientStyle = Infragistics.Win.GradientStyle.Vertical
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectedRowAppearance = Appearance11
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.SelectTypeRow = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.SelectType.[Single]
    Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.TabNavigation = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.TabNavigation.NextControl
    Me.mygrid.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
    Me.mygrid.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(28, 177)
    Me.mygrid.Name = "mygrid"
    Me.mygrid.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(543, 268)
    Me.mygrid.TabIndex = 2
```

The way that I'm binding the data:

```
 Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt = GetData(Order)
            Dim dtcloned As DataTable = dt.Clone()
            dtcloned.Columns(0).DataType = GetType(Integer)
            dtcloned.Columns(1).DataType = GetType(Boolean)
            lblCantidadCont.Text = dt.Rows.Count.ToString()
            For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
                dtcloned.ImportRow(row)
            Next

            mygrid.DataSource = dtcloned
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance this line is wrong (splitted for readability)

```
  Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = 
              Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.RowSelect
```

it should be

```
  Me.mygrid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickAction = 
              Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellClickAction.EditAndSelectText
```

Comment: That's exactly what happened.